# How do I get the Id when clicked on the first row in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-table, react-table-v7

I am pretty new to React and I was following a tutorial to build a react-table, but I wanted to go one step further and see if I can make the first row or cell clickable and get the ID of that cell. However, I am unable to achieve that. I am not sure if this has already been answered, but I could not find any answer.

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
  const getData = async () => {
    const result = await axios
      .get("https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=spider")
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
      });

    return result;
  };

  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Tv Show",
        columns: [
        
          {
            Header: "Name",
            accessor: "show.name",
          },
          {
            Header: "Type",
            accessor: "show.type",
          },
        ],
      },
```

Table.js

```
 return (
          <tr {...row.getRowProps()} data={columns} onClick={checkButton}>
```

This is part of the API

```
[{"score":20.77334,"show":{"id":4107,"url":"https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/4107/spider-man","name":"Spider-Man","type":"Animation","language":"English","genres":["Action","Adventure","Children"],"status":"Ended","runtime":30,"premiered":"1967-09-09","officialSite":null,
```

Tbh I do not know what should be in the checkButton function, I have so many things to get the data, but I am unable to do so. I really appreciate your guidance. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right to use onClick on the table rows. Just add a simple function to check the row index:

```js
const logDataIfFirstRowClicked = (row) => {
    if (row.index === 0) {
      console.log("FIRST ROW CLICKED");
      console.log(row); // returns row object: {id: "0", original: Object, index: 0, depth: 0, cells: Array(2)…} 
      console.log(row.original) // returns the data from the row ex: {actor: "Johnny Depp", movie: "Pirates of the Carribean 1"}
    }
  };
```

and pass it to your table row:

```js
rows.map(row => ({
  <tr {...row.getRowProps()} onClick={() => logDataIfFirstRowClicked(row)}>
}))
```

You can also use the Cell render method in the Column definition to add an on click. If you only want the first cell of each row to return its value on click, it could look like this:

```js
const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Tv Show",
        columns: [
        
          {
            Header: "Name",
            accessor: "show.name",
          },
          {
            Header: "Type",
            accessor: "show.type",
          },
        ],
        // Set the custom cell render here:
        Cell: (cell) => (
          <button
            // add on click to your custom cell
            onClick={() => console.log(cell.value)}
          >
            {" "}
            {cell.value}{" "}
          </button>
        )
      },
    ]
```

Check out this [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-dew-j4l97?file=/src/App.js) and this example on [React-Table's GitHub](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/discussions/2295)

[Row Properties section of React-Table docs](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#row-properties)

Comment: This helps a lot thank you so much. I have one more questions. Is there a way I can get the ID of a row from the API call? E.g if the ID of the first row in the API is '141' how can I get that displayed instead ?

Comment: Nvm I figured it out... It was console.log(row.original.show.id); Thank you for your help :D

Comment: Any idea, how can I get the cell index ?

Comment: The same way, add an onClick to your td instead of the tr. I updated the demo so that if you click the cell, it console.log()'s the cell object. That contains the col obj, row obj, etc

Comment: Yea, that is what I was trying to do. I guess I should I have be more precise with my questions. I was trying to make the first cell of each row clickable rather than the whole row. Any idea about that ? I tried limiting the cell count.

Comment: @Beel, the answer has been updated to show the first cell onclick using the column definitions. I will also suggest you move to a table package that has better documentation, like [ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/).

Comment: Thank you so much! I found a work around by changing the condition inside the onClick method to cell.value === row.original.show.name. I will actually look at ag-Grid since it has better documentation.